# Laravel 5 and iPage Hosting

Tags: laravel-5

I have a shared hosting at iPage. I did the steps listed here : [Deploy Laravel 5 using only FTP in a shared hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29403554/deploy-laravel-5-using-only-ftp-in-a-shared-hosting) (Moving files, editing htaccess) and yet still facing the same 500 error :

> 20161126T060216: bluepenlabs.com/projects/peugeot/public/index.php PHP
>   Warning: 
>   require(/hermes/bosnaweb28a/b1452/ipg.bluepenlabscom/projects/peugeot/public/bootstrap/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /hermes/bosnaweb28a/b1452/ipg.bluepenlabscom/projects/peugeot/public/index.php
>   on line 22 PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   '/hermes/bosnaweb28a/b1452/ipg.bluepenlabscom/projects/peugeot/public/bootstrap/autoload.php'
>
> (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php-5.5.22-amd64/lib/php') in
>   /hermes/bosnaweb28a/b1452/ipg.bluepenlabscom/ 20161126T061559:
>   bluepenlabs.com/projects/peugeot/public/index.php
>
> PHP Parse error: 
>   syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE)
>   in
>   /hermes/bosnaweb28a/b1452/ipg.bluepenlabscom/projects/peugeot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php
>   on line 475
>
> 20161126T061939: bluepenlabs.com/projects/peugeot/public/index.php PHP
>   Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or variable
>   (T_VARIABLE) in
>   /hermes/bosnaweb28a/b1452/ipg.bluepenlabscom/projects/peugeot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php
>   on line 475

Note that i'm trying to install the laravel project in a subdirectory /projects/peugeot/

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once hosted a laravel project on iPage(shared hosting). I faced 500 errors. Not showing much description.

This may be because of the Laravel 5.3 min server requirements.

[image]

Ipage hosting site normally give a version below the min requirement. You need to change the setting on your `Control Panel`. Try upgrading your PHP version.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yup, had to downgrade to laravel 5.1 instead.

Comment: @ChaibiAlaa what PHP version did you had with your iPage hosting ?